# Symfony2 - PHPunit - test method on event subscriber is called

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit

Below is a event subscriber for a 'Test' entity. I have code that assigns a contract and an email needs to be sent when this happens. The code below will send the email. My problem is righting a test that makes sure the method 'sendContractAssignedEmail' was run if the contract property of the test entity is changed from null

```
class TestEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container        
    }

    function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::postUpdate,
        );
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $changeSet = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet( $entity);

    if ($entity instanceof Test && isset($changeSet['contract']) && empty($changeSet['contract'][0]))
        $this->sendContractAssignedEmail($lead);

    }

    private function sendContractAssignedEmail(Test $test)
    {
        //irrelevant code to send email 
    }

}
```

I have a function that assigns a contract on the testHandler

```
public function assign(Test $test, Contract $contract) {

    if (is_null($test->getContract())) {
        $test->setContract($contract);
    }

    return $test;
}
```

this is called from the testController and does trigger the postUpdate event and also does send the email. Im just really struggling on how to test this using PHPunit? I have read a lot but none of it seems to suit what i need. I looked into mocking but Im not sure i understand it correctly

```
public function testEmailSentOnAssignTest() 
    $test = $this->testRepo->getOne(1);
    $objectManager = $this->getObjectManager();

    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Test\TestBundle\EventSubscriber\TestEventsSubscriber')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('sendContractAssignedEmail'))
            ->getMock();

    $args = new LifecycleEventArgs($lead, $objectManager);
    $mock->expects($this->once())->method('sendContractAssignedEmail');
    $mock->postUpdate($args);

}
```

I understand why the above doesn't work i think. The post update function looks for changes to the contract property and there isn't one so the email function is never run. Can i fake the EntityChangeSet somehow or what is the best way to test this event? I'm very new to unit testing so excuse me if I'm miles off!

Comment: You are the right track.  Mock up an entity manager as well as an unit of work and have the uow return a fake change set.  Bit of a pain perhaps but you end up with a nice solid test.  By the way, I found that the Prophecy approach, https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html, while not as well documented, seems to be a bit easier to use.  But that is just an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I  have managed to get a lot further now. The only problem is the 'expects' method doesn't seem to do what i want it to do. It says the method is never invoked but if i put some break points in the code it definitely does call this method :/

Comment: This is because the method im testing to see if its called is private. Is there anything i can do about this

Comment: From a big picture point of view, there should be no need to test private methods.  Nor should you be mocking the class being tested.  One assumes that a mailer object is being used to send emails.  That is what should be mocked.  And try to avoid injecting the complete container.  Just inject what it needs.